# GPU struggling with Flutter animation

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on evaluating the animation capabilities within Flutter. I have a set of cubic paths that I am animating over using `lerpDouble` to find the spot on the curves that I need to paint. While the UI at https://gist.github.com/phpthug/809ac01124e61a7bb0c490709c05a1aa is achieving 60 FPS, the GPU is struggling, maintaining somewhere around 25 FPS. Given that 2dimensions has been able to get extremely advanced animations working, there must be an issue with how I'm re-rendering the widget incorrectly, but for what I'm trying to accomplish, I can't think of a way to optimize redraws. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated in finding a way to optimize the animation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ensure you have a profile ir release build when you evaluate performance. Debug builds have different performance characteristics.

Comment: Running in release mode on a Galaxy S9+, getting a bit higher GPU performance at about 35 FPS.